# Cause Document Error I got CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:UpdateItem on resource

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-ios

I found the document wrong, because the wrong always cannot run success, certainly I also had wrong, I did not see clear, if you suffer now, please just checked as below:

> dynamoDBTableName -> String

In the wrong document, the wrong as below:

> In the "Amazon DynamoDB: Store and Retrieve App Data"
>
> at "Create a DynamoDB Table and Index"

It say

> 3.Enter "Books" as the name of the table

But at sample code write below:

```
Class func dynamoDBTableName () -> String {
       Return "Book"
}
```

Is not return "Book", should return "Books", no wonder, haha, I always got the error "CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: dynamodb: UpdateItem on resource"

If you also always error, checks your table name return same, have nice day.

Answer (score 0):

The error which you are getting indicates that you dont have correct IAM policies attached to your Cognito Role. If you are using an unauth role you need to grant permissions to update item on dynamodb table to that unauth role. Same goes for auth role.

Thanks,
Rohan